# Multiple inserts in SQL without failing on any error

Tags: mysql, sql, go

I've got a use case where I have 15k rows to insert in to two tables. This can't follow the previous results I've seen on here where you just append to a string to do a bulk upload because I need to know which ones failed and which ones passed.

The setup is that there's a writer database and multiple readers, so we can kind of 'hog' the writer database connections temporarily to get this going since reads are on a different node.

The code I've come up with is as follows:

```
type Req struct {
    FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD, FieldE, FieldF string
}
type Result struct {
    ID int
}

type InsertResult struct {
    LastInsertedID int64
    Error          error
}

func (d *DB) InsertRequests(reqs []Req) <-chan InsertResult {
    outChan := make(chan InsertResult, 500)
    go func() {
        defer close(outChan)
        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
        for _, req := range reqs {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(req Req) {
                defer wg.Done()
                tx, err := d.db.Begin()
                if err != nil {
                    outChan <- InsertResult{Error: err}
                    return
                }

                res, err := tx.Exec("INSERT INTO table (a, b, c, d, e, f) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                    req.FieldA, req.FieldB, req.FieldC, req.FieldD, req.FieldE, req.FieldF)

                if err != nil {
                    tx.Rollback()
                    outChan <- InsertResult{Error: err}
                    return
                }

                id, err := res.LastInsertId()
                if err != nil {
                    outChan <- InsertResult{Error: err}
                    return
                }
                tx.Commit()
                outChan <- InsertResult{LastInsertedID: id}
            }(req)
        }

        wg.Wait()
    }()
    return outChan
}
```

Basically, concurrently write to the database with all the inserts and send the results down a buffered channel of the same length.

Does anyone have anything better than this?

Comment: It seems like you keep tx hanging if it failed to retrieve LastInsertId. Maybe drop tx.Rollback() there?

Comment: You maybe could speed things up a little by inserting multiple (batch style) objects during a single tx.